# doubly linked list "unhandled exception" error

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I was creating a double linked list and i got a strange error , spent hours to debug it but could not do so , tried an online debugger and even that didn't help

the program does compile and run but crashes the error i get is

> Unhandled exception at 0x770215ee in double linked list.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

Online debugger results http://onlinegdb.com/Bkta6O6ig

The online debugger gives three errors which i've mentioned in the code below with comments

My guess is that there is something wrong in the add function of class list

**Class Node**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class node
{
private:

    int data;
    node *prev_pointer;
    node *next_pointer;

public:

    int get_data()
    {
        return data;
    }

    void set_data(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }



    node* get_prev_ptr()
    {
        return prev_pointer;
    }

    void set_next_ptr(node *Node)
    {
        next_pointer = Node;
    }

    node* get_next_ptr()
    {
        return next_pointer;
    }


    void set_prev_ptr(node *hi)
    {
        prev_pointer = hi;   //First error
    }
};
```

**Class List**

```
class List
{
private:

    int size;
    node * cursor; 
    node * lastnode;
    node * headnode; 

public:

    List();
    void add(int data);
    bool next();
    void previous();
    void start();
    void traverse();
    int get_data();
//  ~List();
};

List :: List()
{
    headnode = new node();
    cursor = NULL;
    lastnode = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

void List:: add(int data)
{
    node *newnode = new node();
    newnode->set_data(data);

        if ( cursor != NULL )
        {
            newnode->set_next_ptr(cursor->get_next_ptr());
            newnode->set_prev_ptr(cursor);
            (newnode->get_next_ptr())->set_prev_ptr(newnode);  //2nd error
            cursor->set_next_ptr(newnode);
            lastnode = cursor; 
            cursor = cursor->get_next_ptr();
        }
        else 
        {
            newnode->set_next_ptr(NULL);
            newnode->set_prev_ptr(headnode);
            headnode->set_next_ptr(newnode);
            cursor = newnode;
            lastnode = headnode;
        }

    size++;
}

bool List :: next()
{
    if ( cursor != NULL )
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        lastnode = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->get_next_ptr();
    }

    if( cursor == NULL || size == 0 )
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}

void List :: traverse()
{
    node *temp = cursor;
    start();

    for ( int i = 0 ; next() ; i++ )
    {
        cout<<"element  " << i << "  " << cursor->get_data() <<endl;
    }
}

void List :: start()
{
    lastnode = headnode;
    cursor = headnode;
}

int List :: get_data()
{
    return cursor->get_data();
}
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    List list;
    list.add(10);
    list.add(11);         //3rd error 
    list.add(12);
    //list.add(13);
    //list.add(14);
    //list.add(15);

    list.traverse();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The debugger will only help you find problems. It will not find problems for you. `add` does not check that `newnode` was given a non-NULL pointer before trying to use it.. It checks that `cursor` was not NULL, but not that `cursor` 's next is not NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predendum: Reading the debuger output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                          
0x0000000000400d20 in node::set_prev_ptr (this=0x0, hi=0x614c60) at main.cpp:46               
46                      prev_pointer = hi;
```

Note `this=0x0`. All class methods have a this pointer so that they know which of many possible instances to operate on. Here `this` points to NULL. The program cannot get a valid `prev_pointer` from a NULL object. This tells you that, to find the real cause of the problem, you need to find out why `this` is invalid.

This is where the callstack comes in. You move back up the stack to find out where `this` got destroyed. We can see that `set_prev_ptr` uis being invoked on the output of `get_next_ptr` and `get_next_ptr` returns `next_pointer`. First place to look is `next_pointer`. Putting `newnode->next_pointer` into "Display Expressions" shows that `next_pointer` is NULL.

So why is `next_pointer` NULL? Up a few lines of code we find

```
newnode->set_next_ptr(cursor->get_next_ptr())
```

so we look at `cursor->next_pointer` and find it is NULL. And now we get into the original post and draw the linked list because it's a lot faster than running and re-running the debugger over and over.

The best way to debug a linked list is with pencil and paper: Draw it. You will see that after adding 10, the list looks like

```
head <-> 10 -> NULL
cursor -> 10 -> NULL
lastnode -> 10 -> NULL
```

adding 11  should look like

```
head <-> 10 <-> 11 -> NULL
cursor -> 11 -> NULL
lastnode -> 10 -> 11 -> NULL
```

Unfortunately it fails because

```
(newnode->get_next_ptr())->set_prev_ptr(newnode);
```

Attempts

```
11 -> NULL -> 11;
```

So a

```
if (newnode->get_next_ptr() != NULL)
```

is required to protect it.

In addition, rethink

```
lastnode = cursor;
```

as since `cursor`'s next points to `newnode` clearly `cursor` is not the last node. Depending on where `cursor` points, `newnode` may not be the last node either.

Suggestions:

Providing those wide-open next and prev accessors ruins `node`'s encapsulation because anyone can use the accessors to do anything they want to `node`. You might as well declare the member variables `public` and save yourself time.

This looks like a good case for `List` to be a `friend` of `node` or for node to be all `public` access (or a `struct`) and encapsulated within `List` away from prying eyes. Either way, lose the accessors.